# No GPU instances in my region but I can still create VM from machine image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I was able to create a VM with Tesla T4 GPU in **europe-west2** region some time ago, and I created a machine image before destroying the VM.

Now I want to recreate the VM from the machine image in the same region. The paradox is that there's no GPU "Machine family", however I can still create the VM with GPU.

[image: Google Cloud Console. Creating VM from machine image]

I can continue to use it like that for now, but then if I try to create a VM from a snapshot (not MI) I have no option to select GPU in that region.

Does it have something to do with Machine Image taking the quota already? I can't understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot see the GPU tab in machine configuration in europe-west2 region because it supports only the T4 GPU model. Different zones support different GPU models.You can see the GPU tab when zone supports all GPU models(i.e us-central1)

For more information on GPU models refer:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/gpu-regions-zones

2. Machine Configuration details will be displayed automatically when you are creating Vm instance through a machine image. But while creating a Vm instance from a snapshot you have to **“expand the CPU platform and select gpu type”.**

For more information on creating vms with GPUs refer:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/create-vm-with-gpus